# How do I subtract some elements from one array which (element) are already in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have two different arrays and they both contain the same type of element. The elements are obtained from user input. And the arrays can store fixed size of element.

*Let's say that ***fisrt one*** is basically an arrayList and it adds the user input into the list.
The ***second one*** is simply an array which also gets value from user input. All the elements of second array are also contained in the first array and the length of this array is less than the first array*

Now I want to print an array which is the result of  ***first array-second array***.

This is the program I am working on right now. You may avoid this coding just to give me a theoritical concept for doing that.

```
    package issuetracking;

import java.util.*;

public class IssueTrackingObject {

    ArrayList<String> crIss = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean crIss_bool;
    int numOfSolvedIss;
    private String[] solvedIss;

    //lets user create some issues and add them into an arrayList
    public void createIssue() {
        System.out.println("Enter 5 issues: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Issue " + (i + 1 + ": "));
            crIss_bool = crIss.add(input.nextLine());
        }

    }
//Let user mark some issues as solved (which are already in the list that the user has just created)

    public void solvedIssue() {
        System.out.println("How many solved issue you have(Must be less than 5): ");
        numOfSolvedIss = input.nextInt();

        solvedIss = new String[numOfSolvedIss];

        for (int k = 0; k < numOfSolvedIss; k++) {
            System.out.print("Enter solved issue(REMEMBER THAT THE SOLVED ISSUE MUST BE FROM ONE OF THEM YOU ALREADY HAVE CREATED)no. " + (k + 1) + ": ");

            solvedIss[k] = input.next();
        }

    }

    public void printUnsolvedIssue() {
        //print out the elements of createIssue() that doesn't belong to the solvedIssue()

    }
```

Comment: Iterate through the second array, call remove(obj) from the first array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple solution like this:

```
for (String solved : solvediss) {
    if (solved != null) crIss.remove(solved);
}
```

This will remove all the `String`s from the list that are in the array.

Of course, you could also do this.

```
crIss.removeAll(Arrays.asList(solvediss));
```

Comment: One final question please, can u tell me how can I print out unsolved issue as list (instead of an array). Because right now it will remove the element of the second array and print out the first array. But I want that final array to be a list.

Comment: `System.out.println(crIss);`

Answer (score 0):

Go over your second array and use the remove method in arraylist to remove every element of second array from the first.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < solvedIss.length; i++) {
            crIss_bool = crIss.remove(solvedIss[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the elements might be the simplest method in this case, but it causes original list to change.

If you do not wish to have any destructive modification to the original list, you could perform a simple search like following.

```
for (String issue : crIss) {
    bool isUnSolved = true;
    for (String solvedIssue : solvedIss) {
        if (issue.equals(solvedIssue)) {
            isUnSolved = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isUnSolved) {
        // Print the 'issue' or do whatever you want to do with it.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.